# WAMP Stack PHP "Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found"

Tags: php, soap, windows-7, wamp

I have a WAMP (windows (7), apache, mysql, php) stack all setup and running. All is well and it is working and running as expected. I use the machine primarily for development however it is accessible to the outside world. Anyways..

I recently come cross a client with a pre-existing SaaS product where cURL, SOAP, and the like are used. I drop there system onto my server and a bit of jumping around to set it up, get it setup, start plugging away at things to only come across a section where I am getting

> Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found

Naturally my first jump was i forgot to uncomment

> extension=php_soap.dll

Which was true, so I did un-comment it, save the file, then restart the server. However the problem still exists (so I tried even rebooting), now I am stuck as I am not a guru with WAMP/LAMP stacks and configuring them I can only just get around them as needed til now.

Comment: First idea: use phpinfo() to check if you edited the right php.ini file

Comment: did that not listed. Did edit the correct php.ini to my knowledge though

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do you have a `php_soap.dll` in your `php/ext/` folder?

Comment: php_soap.dll, is found in the php/ext/ folder.

Answer (score 13):

This might be a little late now, But I had the similar problem with wamp, and it was because php.ini was different in apache and in cli mode, there was one in apache folder which had php_soap.dll included but the one in php folder which cli was using didn't have it. I add it to the other one and the problem was solved

Comment: Thx Hossein, you made my day :D Solved!

Comment: This is the solution if you enabled SOAP or any other extension through the WAMP Notification area button.

Comment: Hi, I enabled soap in the php.ini of wamp PHP and in the one of Apache of my wampserver 3.0.0 (php 5.6), I enabled openssl too and I restarted all the services but the class SoapClient is still not found. I checked in the phpinfo() and soap is enabled. I don't understand why the class is not found. Please help.

Comment: @Eve As far as I can see, You have done everything right, but there are sometimes slight spelling problems, I suggest you use `get_declared_classes` method to see if SoapClient exists among your declared classes.

Comment: @HosseinShahdoost Hi, thank you for your answer. I don't remember very well the problem but I was in a Symfony project and I believe that I had to write `new \SoapClient(...)` with a back slash at the beginning instead of `new SoapClient(...)` to tell to Symfony that it isn't a framework function but a native php one.

Answer (score 3):

To find the loaded `php.ini` file, load the `phpinfo()` page.
Navigate to that path and open `php.ini` in notepad and search for `php_soap.dll` in it.

Uncomment this line and save the file before restarting the server.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably checked this, but what version of PHP are you using? SoapClient only available after 5.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Uncommenting it in `php.ini` didn't work.  I had to uncomment it in `php.ini-development` and `php.ini-production`.  They were all in `C:/BitNami/wampstack-.../php`