# Why I am getting Class "SoapClient' not found in..etc"

Tags: php, soap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WAMP Stack PHP “Fatal error: Class ‘SoapClient’ not found”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760716/wamp-stack-php-fatal-error-class-soapclient-not-found)

I downloaded a library from this site [library](https://github.com/Exeu/Amazon-ECS-PHP-Library/downloads) and when I tried to use it's examples it says : "Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in C:\wamp\www\Amazon-ECS\Exeu-Amazon-ECS-PHP-Library-9030053\lib\AmazonECS.class.php on line 231" How should I able to fix this?

```
    <?php
/**
 * Amazon ECS Class
 * http://www.amazon.com
 * =====================
 *
 * This class fetchs productinformation via the Product Advertising API by Amazon (formerly ECS).
 * It supports three basic operations: ItemSearch, ItemLookup and BrowseNodeLookup.
 * These operations could be expanded with extra prarmeters to specialize the query.
 *
 * Requirement is the PHP extension SOAP.
 *
 * @package      AmazonECS
 * @license      http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.txt GPL
 * @version      1.3.4-DEV
 * @author       Exeu <exeu65@googlemail.com>
 * @contributor  Julien Chaumond <chaumond@gmail.com>
 * @link         http://github.com/Exeu/Amazon-ECS-PHP-Library/wiki Wiki
 * @link         http://github.com/Exeu/Amazon-ECS-PHP-Library Source
 */
class AmazonECS
{
  const RETURN_TYPE_ARRAY  = 1;
  const RETURN_TYPE_OBJECT = 2;

  /**
   * Baseconfigurationstorage
   *
   * @var array
   */
  private $requestConfig = array(
    'requestDelay' => false
  );

  /**
   * Responseconfigurationstorage
   *
   * @var array
   */
  private $responseConfig = array(
    'returnType'          => self::RETURN_TYPE_OBJECT,
    'responseGroup'       => 'Small',
    'optionalParameters'  => array()
  );

  /**
   * All possible locations
   *
   * @var array
   */
  private $possibleLocations = array('de', 'com', 'co.uk', 'ca', 'fr', 'co.jp', 'it', 'cn', 'es');

  /**
   * The WSDL File
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $webserviceWsdl = 'http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl';

  /**
   * The SOAP Endpoint
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $webserviceEndpoint = 'https://webservices.amazon.%%COUNTRY%%/onca/soap?Service=AWSECommerceService';

  /**
   * @param string $accessKey
   * @param string $secretKey
   * @param string $country
   * @param string $associateTag
   */
  public function __construct($accessKey, $secretKey, $country, $associateTag)
  {
    if (empty($accessKey) || empty($secretKey))
    {
      throw new Exception('No Access Key or Secret Key has been set');
    }

    $this->requestConfig['accessKey']     = $accessKey;
    $this->requestConfig['secretKey']     = $secretKey;
    $this->associateTag($associateTag);
    $this->country($country);
  }

  /**
   * execute search
   *
   * @param string $pattern
   *
   * @return array|object return type depends on setting
   *
   * @see returnType()
   */
  public function search($pattern, $nodeId = null)
  {
    if (false === isset($this->requestConfig['category']))
    {
      throw new Exception('No Category given: Please set it up before');
    }

    $browseNode = array();
    if (null !== $nodeId && true === $this->validateNodeId($nodeId))
    {
      $browseNode = array('BrowseNode' => $nodeId);
    }

    $params = $this->buildRequestParams('ItemSearch', array_merge(
      array(
        'Keywords' => $pattern,
        'SearchIndex' => $this->requestConfig['category']
      ),
      $browseNode
    ));

    return $this->returnData(
      $this->performSoapRequest("ItemSearch", $params)
    );
  }

  /**
   * execute ItemLookup request
   *
   * @param string $asin
   *
   * @return array|object return type depends on setting
   *
   * @see returnType()
   */
  public function lookup($asin)
  {
    $params = $this->buildRequestParams('ItemLookup', array(
      'ItemId' => $asin,
    ));

    return $this->returnData(
      $this->performSoapRequest("ItemLookup", $params)
    );
  }

  /**
   * Implementation of BrowseNodeLookup
   * This allows to fetch information about nodes (children anchestors, etc.)
   *
   * @param integer $nodeId
   */
  public function browseNodeLookup($nodeId)
  {
    $this->validateNodeId($nodeId);

    $params = $this->buildRequestParams('BrowseNodeLookup', array(
      'BrowseNodeId' => $nodeId
    ));

    return $this->returnData(
      $this->performSoapRequest("BrowseNodeLookup", $params)
    );
  }

  /**
   * Implementation of SimilarityLookup
   * This allows to fetch information about product related to the parameter product
   *
   * @param string $asin
   */
  public function similarityLookup($asin)
  {
    $params = $this->buildRequestParams('SimilarityLookup', array(
      'ItemId' => $asin
    ));

    return $this->returnData(
      $this->performSoapRequest("SimilarityLookup", $params)
    );
  }

  /**
   * Builds the request parameters
   *
   * @param string $function
   * @param array  $params
   *
   * @return array
   */
  protected function buildRequestParams($function, array $params)
  {
    $associateTag = array();

    if(false === empty($this->requestConfig['associateTag']))
    {
      $associateTag = array('AssociateTag' => $this->requestConfig['associateTag']);
    }

    return array_merge(
      $associateTag,
      array(
        'AWSAccessKeyId' => $this->requestConfig['accessKey'],
        'Request' => array_merge(
          array('Operation' => $function),
          $params,
          $this->responseConfig['optionalParameters'],
          array('ResponseGroup' => $this->prepareResponseGroup())
    )));
  }

  /**
   * Prepares the responsegroups and returns them as array
   *
   * @return array|prepared responsegroups
   */
  protected function prepareResponseGroup()
  {
    if (false === strstr($this->responseConfig['responseGroup'], ','))
      return $this->responseConfig['responseGroup'];

    return explode(',', $this->responseConfig['responseGroup']);
  }

  /**
   * @param string $function Name of the function which should be called
   * @param array $params Requestparameters 'ParameterName' => 'ParameterValue'
   *
   * @return array The response as an array with stdClass objects
   */
  protected function performSoapRequest($function, $params)
  {
    if (true ===  $this->requestConfig['requestDelay']) {
      sleep(1);
    }

    $soapClient = new SoapClient(
      $this->webserviceWsdl,
      array('exceptions' => 1)
    );

    $soapClient->__setLocation(str_replace(
      '%%COUNTRY%%',
      $this->responseConfig['country'],
      $this->webserviceEndpoint
    ));

    $soapClient->__setSoapHeaders($this->buildSoapHeader($function));

    return $soapClient->__soapCall($function, array($params));
  }

  /**
   * Provides some necessary soap headers
   *
   * @param string $function
   *
   * @return array Each element is a concrete SoapHeader object
   */
  protected function buildSoapHeader($function)
  {
    $timeStamp = $this->getTimestamp();
    $signature = $this->buildSignature($function . $timeStamp);

    return array(
      new SoapHeader(
        'http://security.amazonaws.com/doc/2007-01-01/',
        'AWSAccessKeyId',
        $this->requestConfig['accessKey']
      ),
      new SoapHeader(
        'http://security.amazonaws.com/doc/2007-01-01/',
        'Timestamp',
        $timeStamp
      ),
      new SoapHeader(
        'http://security.amazonaws.com/doc/2007-01-01/',
        'Signature',
        $signature
      )
    );
  }

  /**
   * provides current gm date
   *
   * primary needed for the signature
   *
   * @return string
   */
  final protected function getTimestamp()
  {
    return gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");
  }

  /**
   * provides the signature
   *
   * @return string
   */
  final protected function buildSignature($request)
  {
    return base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $request, $this->requestConfig['secretKey'], true));
  }

  /**
   * Basic validation of the nodeId
   *
   * @param integer $nodeId
   *
   * @return boolean
   */
  final protected function validateNodeId($nodeId)
  {
    if (false === is_numeric($nodeId) || $nodeId <= 0)
    {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Node has to be a positive Integer.'));
    }

    return true;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the response either as Array or Array/Object
   *
   * @param object $object
   *
   * @return mixed
   */
  protected function returnData($object)
  {
    switch ($this->responseConfig['returnType'])
    {
      case self::RETURN_TYPE_OBJECT:
        return $object;
      break;

      case self::RETURN_TYPE_ARRAY:
        return $this->objectToArray($object);
      break;

      default:
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
          "Unknwon return type %s", $this->responseConfig['returnType']
        ));
      break;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Transforms the responseobject to an array
   *
   * @param object $object
   *
   * @return array An arrayrepresentation of the given object
   */
  protected function objectToArray($object)
  {
    $out = array();
    foreach ($object as $key => $value)
    {
      switch (true)
      {
        case is_object($value):
          $out[$key] = $this->objectToArray($value);
        break;

        case is_array($value):
          $out[$key] = $this->objectToArray($value);
        break;

        default:
          $out[$key] = $value;
        break;
      }
    }

    return $out;
  }

  /**
   * set or get optional parameters
   *
   * if the argument params is null it will reutrn the current parameters,
   * otherwise it will set the params and return itself.
   *
   * @param array $params the optional parameters
   *
   * @return array|AmazonECS depends on params argument
   */
  public function optionalParameters($params = null)
  {
    if (null === $params)
    {
      return $this->responseConfig['optionalParameters'];
    }

    if (false === is_array($params))
    {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
        "%s is no valid parameter: Use an array with Key => Value Pairs", $params
      ));
    }

    $this->responseConfig['optionalParameters'] = $params;

    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * Set or get the country
   *
   * if the country argument is null it will return the current
   * country, otherwise it will set the country and return itself.
   *
   * @param string|null $country
   *
   * @return string|AmazonECS depends on country argument
   */
  public function country($country = null)
  {
    if (null === $country)
    {
      return $this->responseConfig['country'];
    }

    if (false === in_array(strtolower($country), $this->possibleLocations))
    {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
        "Invalid Country-Code: %s! Possible Country-Codes: %s",
        $country,
        implode(', ', $this->possibleLocations)
      ));
    }

    $this->responseConfig['country'] = strtolower($country);

    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * Setting/Getting the amazon category
   *
   * @param string $category
   *
   * @return string|AmazonECS depends on category argument
   */
  public function category($category = null)
  {
    if (null === $category)
    {
      return isset($this->requestConfig['category']) ? $this->requestConfig['category'] : null;
    }

    $this->requestConfig['category'] = $category;

    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * Setting/Getting the responsegroup
   *
   * @param string $responseGroup Comma separated groups
   *
   * @return string|AmazonECS depends on responseGroup argument
   */
  public function responseGroup($responseGroup = null)
  {
    if (null === $responseGroup)
    {
      return $this->responseConfig['responseGroup'];
    }

    $this->responseConfig['responseGroup'] = $responseGroup;

    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * Setting/Getting the returntype
   * It can be an object or an array
   *
   * @param integer $type Use the constants RETURN_TYPE_ARRAY or RETURN_TYPE_OBJECT
   *
   * @return integer|AmazonECS depends on type argument
   */
  public function returnType($type = null)
  {
    if (null === $type)
    {
      return $this->responseConfig['returnType'];
    }

    $this->responseConfig['returnType'] = $type;

    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * Setter/Getter of the AssociateTag.
   * This could be used for late bindings of this attribute
   *
   * @param string $associateTag
   *
   * @return string|AmazonECS depends on associateTag argument
   */
  public function associateTag($associateTag = null)
  {
    if (null === $associateTag)
    {
      return $this->requestConfig['associateTag'];
    }

    $this->requestConfig['associateTag'] = $associateTag;

    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * @deprecated use returnType() instead
   */
  public function setReturnType($type)
  {
    return $this->returnType($type);
  }

  /**
   * Setting the resultpage to a specified value.
   * Allows to browse resultsets which have more than one page.
   *
   * @param integer $page
   *
   * @return AmazonECS
   */
  public function page($page)
  {
    if (false === is_numeric($page) || $page <= 0)
    {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
        '%s is an invalid page value. It has to be numeric and positive',
        $page
      ));
    }

    $this->responseConfig['optionalParameters'] = array_merge(
      $this->responseConfig['optionalParameters'],
      array("ItemPage" => $page)
    );

    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * Enables or disables the request delay.
   * If it is enabled (true) every request is delayed one second to get rid of the api request limit.
   *
   * Reasons for this you can read on this site:
   * https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/faq.html
   *
   * By default the requestdelay is disabled
   *
   * @param boolean $enable true = enabled, false = disabled
   *
   * @return boolean|AmazonECS depends on enable argument
   */
  public function requestDelay($enable = null)
  {
    if (false === is_null($enable) && true === is_bool($enable))
    {
      $this->requestConfig['requestDelay'] = $enable;

      return $this;
    }

    return $this->requestConfig['requestDelay'];
  }
}
```

Comment: It's probably not found cause you're trying to include it with an incorrect path. We can't know this based on what you provided. You'd need to post your code for how you're including and instantiating the class.

Comment: Requirement is the PHP SOAP extension...

Comment: I was suggesting you update your question with actual code so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: @KaiQing, I'm just using localhost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error appears to be caused by the version of PHP that you have does not have the SOAP extension enabled.

To resolve this simply start wamp, click on the wamp system tray icon. Within this screen select PHP then PHP extensions. This will display a list of extensions. Ensure that php_soap is ticked.

If you intend to access soap servers that use HTTPs then you will also ensure php_openssl is ticked.

Comment: I'm just using localhost

Comment: Hi Sui i personally have not used Wamp for some time but checking http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,37132,48503 you click on the wamp system icon tray, then php, then php extensions. Finally ensure that php_soap is ticked.

Comment: Thanks! now I ve got this new error SoapClient::__doRequest(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Comment: try following my previous comment but this time look for an extension called php_openssl

Comment: Hi, I enabled soap and openssl extensions in my wamp, restarted all services but SoapClient is still not found. I checked in the phpinfo() and soap is enabled so I don't understand why I have this error... Please help.